# How is this operation called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, babeljs

```
[a,,b] = [1,2,3]
```

I can't seem to find anything about it on MDN, google was not very helpful either.

Comment: it is called: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Yes, it is the thing, tanks